# How to bind large no of Rows to DataGrid faster using MVVM

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

I have an MVVM application in which I had to bind large no of Records to DataGrid from View Model.

Actually I will get user  information, quantity of items to buy and a serial number from user. If the user enter the quantity as 1000 and Serial Number as 1234, I need to create 1000 records with the serial number starting as 1234 and for each record it will be incremented by 1. When creating the serial no, i need to check if it is already present in the DB.

My Code:

```
        for(var i=0;i<Quantity;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                acquisition.ContactName = Contact;
                acquisition.Date = AcquisitionDate;
                acquisition.UserNotes = UserNotes;

                if (IsMultipleChecked)
                {
                    acquisition.SerialNumber = SerialPrefix + acquisition.SerialNumber + SerialSuffix;
                }

                if (IsSerialInLogs(acquisition.SerialNumber) || IsSerialNumberUsed(acquisition.SerialNumber))
                {
                    errors.AppendLine(acquisition.SerialNumber + " has already been used.");
                    continue;
                }

                if (!IsItemSelected)
                {
                    Acquisitions.Add(acquisition);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errors.AppendLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        var acquisitionRepository = _repositoryFactory.Get<Acquisition>();
        Acquisitions.Where(a => a.AcquisitionId == default(long)).ToList().ForEach(acquisitionRepository.Add);
        acquisitionRepository.Commit();
        AcquisitionCollectionView.Refresh();
```

Here IsSerialInLogs and IsSerialNumberUsed are the method used to check if the serial number already exists in two different table.

Acquisitions is a list to Which the 1000 record will be inserted and the record in the list will be added to another table.

And finally my datagrid AcquisitionCollectionView will be Refreshed to bind the datas.

All this process take more than 2 mins. Do any one advice on how to do it faster or provide with any sample code or link which may help to overcome this problem..
And this is done using MVVM

Comment: How does your `IsSerialInLogs()` and `IsSerialNumberUsed()` work internal? you can check for your performance drawdown by using [Stopwatch](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch)

Comment: No any MVVM will help you to insert 1000 records DB and make it faster. But you may bind your UI to ViewModel property and update this property async. Is it the same what you want?

Comment: For 1 record it takes less than a second

Comment: I think you need to do some benchmarking to find which portion of the process takes the longest and start trying to improve that. It's too difficult for us to tell from this limited sample. Also: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/